# Automatically removing Private IP's in Route53 private hosted Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-route53, autoscaling

I have a self-deployed elasticsearch cluster on AWS, where the instances are autoscaled and behind a private VPC and do not have public ip assigned to them. I have a custom domain and recordset in Route 53 as
elasticsearch.pers-z.infra.abc-appanalytics.com : 
A
10.0.7.142 
10.0.8.43 
10.0.9.74

Now suppose one of the instances fail, how do i remove that entry from the recordset. When i say fail, it could be elasticsearch not responding on port 9200 Or the instance itself shuts down.

What are the options for me in this context ?

PS: Route53 Health Checks do not support private-ips

Comment: Offtopic. This site is for programming questions, not server/network/hosting configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [elasticsearch-cloud-aws](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws) (now [discovery-ec2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.0/discovery-ec2-usage.html)). It will automatically cope with the elasticsearch cluster.

You need to add it in elasticsearch config:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    access_key: you_key
    secret_key: you_key
    region: region

discovery.type: ec2
discovery.ec2.groups: you_security_group
```